# How to remove name and keep just tld in a domain name string PHP & Regex

Tags: php, regex, string

[PHP] I want to strip off domain keyword and leave just TLD. How do i achieve it? I tried some string functions with help of Regex Patterns but they only support 1 domain. But you can see i have multiple entries.

Original String:

```
{
   "example.biz":"Available",
   "example.co":"Available",
   "example.com":"Unavailable",
   "example.mobi":"Available",
   "example.net":"Unavailable",
   "example.org":"Unavailable"
}
```

Intended Output.

```
{
   "biz":"Available",
   "co":"Available",
   "com":"Unavailable",
   "mobi":"Available",
   "net":"Unavailable",
   "org":"Unavailable"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex to achieve this. Your string looks like valid JSON. You can parse it to an array using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) (with second parameter set as `TRUE` to get an associative array) and then remove everything before the `.` using [`strstr()`](http://php.net/strstr) and [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/ltrim):

```
$string = <<<'EOD'
{
   "example.biz":"Available",
   "example.co":"Available",
   "example.com":"Unavailable",
   "example.mobi":"Available",
   "example.net":"Unavailable",
   "example.org":"Unavailable"
}
EOD;

$jsonArr = json_decode($string, TRUE);
$result = array();

foreach ($jsonArr as $domain => $status) {
    $newkey = ltrim(strstr($domain, '.'), '.');
    $result[$newkey] = $status;
}

echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
{
    "biz": "Available",
    "co": "Available",
    "com": "Unavailable",
    "mobi": "Available",
    "net": "Unavailable",
    "org": "Unavailable"
}
```

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/128564)

Comment: Of course... `.co.uk` needs consideration, as do all other TLDs that are locked to the second level. And it'll only get worse come July when `.uk` *opens up* at the second level...

Comment: if *"example."* is a known constant surely it's better to just strip that?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I know it doesn't handle all the corner cases. It's just a nudge in the right direction. The OP should update it with according to his/her requirements. In general, what you said is true :)

Comment: @Emissary: I don't think that's the case. Maybe the OP replaced the actual domain names with `example.tld`?

Comment: Hmm... it might be better to assume two-letter domains aren't valid (as they are almost universally restricted to very specific entities) and use a regex based on that. Fewer corner cases, I think.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Or validate based on the [list of valid TLDs](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt). We don't know what the OP is using this for, so it's up to him to decide whether or not to account for these corner cases.